# Magento: How to get attribute option name(code) in cart instead of just label and value

Tags: php, magento

In cart there is `getOptionList`, which returns the label value of selected attributes.  I'm trying to get the code of an attribute, instead of the translation label.  Something like `getAttributeCode`. or `getOptionCode`. The problem is that `getOptionList` returns an array of label and value, not classes. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

it'll return an array of with that text value and code of each of the options for the attribute.

if you just want the code of the attribute you can call:

```
$attribute->getAttributeCode();
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use this code in Cart page in Magento 1.8.1.0?